# Saving results of df.show()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to capture the contents of a field from a table in order to append it to a filename. I have sorted the renaming process. Is there anyway I can save the output of the following in order to append it to renamed file? I can't use Scala, it has to be in python

```py
    df = sqlContext.sql("select replace(value,'-','') from dbsmets1mig02_technical_build.tbl_Tech_admin_data where type = 'Week_Starting'")
    df.show()
```

Comment: Did you try `x = df.show()`?? I think the output of `df.show()` is saved now in `x`

Comment: Hi Anwarvic, unfortunately your solution didn't work. The content of x is 'none'

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `df` object into a pandas DataFrame/Series object, then can use other Python commands more easily on this;

```
pandasdf = df.toPandas()
```

Once you have this as a pandas data frame - *say it looks something like this;*

```
import pandas as pd
pandasdf = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["20191122"]})
```

Then you can pull out the string and use `f` strings to join it into a filename;

```
date = pandasdf.iloc[0, 0]
filename = f"my_file_{date}.csv"
```

Then we have the `filename` object as `'my_file_20191122.csv'`

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm new to all this. How would I apply the panda df to the file rename. I'm currently here after the previous suggestion 'code' fname = "DR_SSE002_70-B3-D5-1F-30-66-30-00_CGI_RG_" + str(x) + ".csv"'code'

Comment: @RG0107 can you please give an example of the output from `df.show()` - I'm not exactly sure what data you have (dimensions etc), so it makes it difficult to give an answer. Thank you!

Comment: all that appears in the output is a date, '20191122' which I want to append to a filename

Comment: apologies for the delay in responding, I've only just seen your response. I'll give it a go and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit, but it gives me what I need, many thanks, I've spent ages trying to hunt this down. I ended up doing this  filename="my_file" + str(date) + ".csv"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using indexing?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Name':['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter'],
                    'Planned_Start':['1/1/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/15/2019', '1/2/2019'], 
                    'Duration':[2, 3, 5, 6], 
                    'Hrs':[0.6, 1, 1.2, 0.3]})

df.iloc[3][1]
```

The syntax is df.iloc[< index of row containing desired enty >][< position of your entry >]

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: used in solution above